# How to assert if selected option from drop down is choosen. Selenium. Page Object Model

Tags: java, selenium, automated-tests

I need to select option from drop list and check if this option is choosen / visible for user. Code for choosing option:

```
@FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "id_state")
public WebElement StateDropDown;

 public void ChooseState(String index){
    Select Choose = new Select(StateDropDown);
    Choose.selectByVisibleText(index);
```

This is my drop down:

```
<select name="id_state" id="id_state" class="form-control">
<option value="">-</option>
<option value="1">Alabama</option>
<option value="2">Alaska</option>
<option value="3">Arizona</option>
<option </select>
```

I want to choose 'Alabama'and use assert to check if 'Alabama' is in fact choosen. I understand that I have to write a function which sends a name of choosen state to string. Assert it's going to be included here:

```
@Then("^I see \"([^\"]*)\" in dropdown$")
public void iSeeInDropdown(String state) 
Assert.assertEquals("Alabama",??????);}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Select class, there is a method called 'getFirstSelectedOption()' which will return the selected web element option from the drop down. By using this method, you can retrieve the option like below:

```
Select select = new Select(someElement);
String option = select.getFirstSelectedOption().getText();
```

The you can assert the condition like below:

`Assert.assertEquals("Alabama", option)`;

Try to follow the below steps,

Add the below method in the page objects class :

```
public String getSelected() {
            return new Select(StateDropDown).getFirstSelectedOption().getText().trim();
        }
```

And modify this step definition method like below, which will call the method of the page objects class and then get the selected option and assert it.

```
@Then("^I see \"([^\"]*)\" in dropdown$") {
        public void iSeeInDropdown(String state) 
            String selectedOption = new PageObjects().getSelected();
            Assert.assertEquals("Alabama", selectedOption);
        }
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: I think the trim() method is not required. If leading or trailing spaces are present in UI, the test will pass instead of failing.

Comment: @Grasshopper Yeah! May or may not the trim() method is required. Thanks for pointing out, let the questioner decide it.